# UIPageViewController with PageControl

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, pagecontrol

I'm using a UIPageViewController to display 4 other ViewControllers. So my RootViewController is a PageViewController which displays 4 other ViewControllers I created in my Storyboard with segues to different Views . All works perfect. But is it possible to add an UIPageControl to this PageViewController. Is this possible anyhow?

Or has someone an idea how I can achieve a similar result?

Would be great, thanks!

Comment: What tutorial did you use, i'd like to do the same thing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to implement these `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods:

**Swift**

```swift
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int { ... }
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int { ... }
```

**Obj-C**

```c
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

And you'll get a page control showing up at the bottom 36px of your UIPageViewController. Try changing the color of the view to a dark color, if you can't see them.

Comment: Funnily enough, your question also helped me — I had that code in as boilerplate, and was wondering why there was a white strip at the bottom of my view. So thanks, too :)

Comment: Haha that's good to hear that it helped you too :) - do you know if you can change the color of the points? and how do I hide the black bar at the bottom? Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: just FYI UIPageViewController has to transition style set to scroll. Page curl doesn't show UIPageControl